# Change height of the "header view" inside UITableView

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I added a view "Header View" inside a table view (see structure in screenshot). It has fixed height. I tried to change view's frame size, view is getting smaller, but there is still empty space between header and tableview cells.
I need to change header height dynamically in code. Any suggestions?

[image: IB stracture]

[image: actual screen]

Comment: What is header view used for? Is it the space between Customer Details and Related Transactions?

Comment: @sahara108 it's a view which contains Customer details, etc.  I added it inside tableview, so it scrolls with the tableview

Comment: I don't know why you need this header view. But how do you make space for showing it or it just overlaps other cell? Can you post some code?

Comment: this view is in the top and when you scroll it scrolls with the cells. Related transactions in the screenshot is the 1st section in the tableview, everything above it is header view

Answer (score 0):

In your tableview's delegate, you have to use

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return /*desired height*/;
}
```

**EDIT**

According to your comment, if you don't want to change your interface, what you can do is to set a height constraint to that view.
You then make a reference of the constraint to the header of the controller managing the view.

In the code, you can then change the height by changing the value of the constraint and updating the view :

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:/*animation time in seconds*/ animations:^{
    yourHeightConstraint.constant = /*desired height*/;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}];
[self.view updateConstraints];
```

Comment: Please take a look to the screenshot, it's not a header for section, but a separate view inside tableview

Comment: Can you give me more precisions about this view ? Do you want it to have its height set before running code ? Or do you want to change it within ?

Comment: I want to change height within the code, because there is button, which can be hidden, the problem is I get empty space when it's hidden, so I need to change height for the view

Comment: thanks for the update, I wanted to do exactly the same, the problem is IB doesn't allow me to set any constraints for this view :( add a view inside tableview and try to set constraint, you will see what I mean

Comment: Maybe the easiest thing you could do is desigh two prototype cells. One for the customers details, and another one for the related transactions. Call the one you need in method `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` with their identifier

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you move the `Header View` out as a subview of `View`, set a tag to it, then in `viewForHeaderInSection`, use the tag to get it. Set the proper height in `heightForHeaderInSection`. When height changes, refresh tableView. The reason for that is `Header View` is no longer a subview of the table view, it will always stick to the first table view row.

Also with the current design you can make the `Header View` a cell, then in the `viewForHeaderInSection` you can reuse the cell, if you have multiple sections this is the way to go.

Comment: Actually it's not a section header, but a separate view which should be scrollable with the table view and it should not stick in the top when you scroll.

Comment: So where is this view, in the middle of table cells?

Comment: it's above cells, everything above related transactions is inside this view. And it scrolls perfectly with the tableview

Comment: I did a test that if you make the header view's height decrease like 10,there will be a 10 point white space between it and the first row,how do you compensate for that if you decrease the height of tableview? The bottom of the tableview will be clipped and the first row will not pushed up to fill the 10 point,if I am going to do that,I will make the header view out of the table and you can set vertical constraint between them, or set the header view as a cell in the tableView.

Comment: If I set vertical constraint, it will not scroll with the tableview. Making it a cell is not a good option as well, as I have 3 sections, it will make things complicated

Comment: Yes,then that option is out,do you have this header view above all 3 sections? Can you make it section header view?

Comment: I considered making it section header, but don't know how. It's very complicated view